# What do I do when I use the pillow module to take one screenshot and it takes several instead?

Tags: python, recursion, python-imaging-library, screenshot

I am trying to take several screeenshots with Python each time I press the key 'p' on my keyboard, with the page number being updated with each new screenshot. However, the program ends up taking several screenshots with each press of the key.

```
    from PIL import ImageGrab
    import keyboard

    def shot(number):
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
                 image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(580, 0, 1340, 1080))
                 image.save(f"{number} page.pdf")
                 shot(number + 1)
            else:
                 pass

    for i in range(1, 2):
            shot(i)
```

Comment: This is not the first method I used. It is only the most recent.

Comment: The `while` loop will never end and take screenshots as long as `p` is pressed. In addition it is recursive, calling itself again and again.

Comment: So how do I fix it? By removing the loop? But I do intend for the function to be recursive, so it gives me a new page number every time.

Comment: @ChanneyCrockern Please do not vandalize your post, you agree with code sharing by posting on this website - see [licence](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). Your code is not special in any way, so I see no reason to not share it. Also it is usually good to accept the post that helped you to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import keyboard

def shot(number):
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
             image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(580, 0, 1340, 1080))
             image.save(f"{number} page.pdf")
             shot(number + 1)
             break #to break loop
        else:
             pass

for i in range(1, 2):
        shot(i)
```

Comment: It still takes too many screenshots with each press of the key.

Comment: maybe reason is your for loop

Comment: I'm very new to Python. How do I do that please?

Comment: use pynput and create listner

Comment: Thank you very much. The sleep module was all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is recursion you use, you call it right after you take screen, try this:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import keyboard
import time

def shot(number):
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
                 image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(580, 0, 1340, 1080))
                 image.save(f"{number} page.pdf")
                 break
            else:
                 pass

i=1
while True:
    shot(i)
    #suspend for a second, so we don't take another screen immediately 
    time.sleep(1)
    i+=1
```

But there is way simpler method, you don't need to use loops if you use `keyboard.wait`, which is also way more efficient.

Also to avoid memory consumption we can get rid of recursion with a simple loop:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import keyboard
import time

def shot(number):
    keyboard.wait("p")
    image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(580, 0, 1340, 1080))
    image.save(f"{number} page.pdf")
    time.sleep(1)

i=1
while True:
    shot(i)
    i+=1
```